# Split data frame and write to csv

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, split, subset

I have a data frame such as:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 100),
             var2 = rep(c('x', 'w', 'y', 'z'), 75),
             var3 = rep(c('one', 'two'), each = 150),
             value = 1:300)
```

I want to automatically split this into data frames and write to csv files for each unique group of variables. This would give me 3 * 4 * 2 = 24 separate data frames and resulting csv files. I want these to be titled, 'var1_var2_var3.csv' for each combination (for example, 'a_x_one.csv'

How can I automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` to split dataframe by one or more factors and pass subsets into a function as parameter:

```
by_df_list <- by(df, df[,c("var1", "var2", "var3")], function(sub){

  file_name <- paste(max(as.character(sub$var1)), 
                     max(as.character(sub$var2)),
                     max(as.character(sub$var3)), sep="_")

  write.csv(sub, paste0(file_name, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)

  return(sub)
})
```

Comment: That's perfect for part 1, subsetting the data frame. How can I do the next step, of now exporting all those data frames to separate csv files with the filenames I want?

Comment: You obviously did not run the solution with your sample data. There is a `write.csv` call!

Comment: ah! Thank you. My export directory was set somewhere that I didn't see it.